# ionic and angularjs time null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to build app via ionic and angularjs content schedule flight time, every thing is okay, but the problem is the data of json in time section,  some time he dont know the time of dep or arr and he show result is `"null"` and in html show me 03:00am incorrectly.

data json get null if he dont know the time of flight :

```
              "estimated": {
                "departure": null,
                "arrival": null
              },
```

html code use : `<p>{{arr.timearrvie * 1000 | date:'shortTime'}}</p>`

I want to make if time get null, I want to show another thing like text null  , not show me 03:00 am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't check for a correct value before multiplying by 1000:

```
<p>{{arr.timearrvie ? (arr.timearrvie * 1000 | date:'shortTime') : 'null'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The date filter won't display anything on null value but since the `* 1000` part give a number `0` it tricks it to thinks it is a timestamp.

One way without involving a custom filter, or the ternary supported by angular `> 1.1.5`

```
{{ (date && date * 1000 || date ) | date:'shortTime' }}
```